# How to solve pass thorugh command ignored issue when setting a signal analyser MXA N9020A

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am trying to set up the signal analyser using a simple python script. I am able to set the center and frequency and span frequency but when i am trying to turn the average on and set it to exponential mode, it gives me a pass through command ignored. The instrument is connected successfully using LAN.

```
import string

import pyvisa # PyVISA package for connecting to the instrument

 

pyvisa.log_to_screen()

 

# Make connection to instrument

# Open a VISA resource manager pointing to the installation folder for the Keysight Visa libraries.

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()

 

# Device addr

addr_MXA = 'TCPIP0::A-N9020A-00060::inst0::INSTR'

addr_VSA = 'TCPIP0::CASCODA500::hislip1::INSTR'

SA_device = rm.open_resource(addr_VSA)

 

# Preset and wait for operation to complete

SA_device.write('*rst')

SA_device.query('*opc?')

 

# Resume the sweeping

SA_device.write('init:cont ON')

SA_device.write('init:res')

 

# Measurement variables for the MeasSetup

freq = '2.44GHz'

freq_span = '5MHz'

count = 10

avermode = 'EXP'

search_len = '832us'

 

SA_device.write('sens:freq:cent {}'.format(freq))

SA_device.write('sens:freq:span {}'.format(freq_span))

# Average

SA_device.write('sens:aver ON')

SA_device.write('sens:mon:aver:tcon {}'.format(avermode))

SA_device.write('sens:aver:count {}'.format(count))
```

[The SCPI log of Keysight VSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwZdi.png)

Comment: This happens because I was trying to use SCPI commands for MXA N9020A instrument on 89600VSA software running on the computer. This is solved by downloading Keysight Command Expert and use the commands that are tailored for different instruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because I was trying to use SCPI commands for MXA N9020A instrument on 89600 VSA software running on the computer. This is solved by downloading Keysight Command Expert and use the commands that are tailored for different instruments and also using SCPI reference guide [here](https://rfmw.em.keysight.com/wireless/helpfiles/89600b/WebHelp-scpi/scpiref.htm).